# How to disable keyboard for XPages modal dialog?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, xpages-extlib

for Bootstrap modals I can disable the keyboard:

```
$('#modal-id').modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
    });
```

How can achieve something similar for the EXTLIB modal dialogs?

You tend to call them via:

```
XSP.openDialog('#{id:inPlaceDialog1}')
```

The idea is to present a dialog after the user has submitted a document. The dialog should contain a message and a button which would redirect to another Xpage

Comment: Disabling the keyboard does make the application less accessible. Why would you want to do that? It is a common expectation that Enter or ESC closes a dialog presented. Any reason to ignore this convention?

Comment: i want the user have only the click the button in the dialog option :-)

Comment: Usability requires that they can reach the buttons by keyboard too. Seems what you want is to ensure users have taken notice. Disabling the keyboard isn’t suitable for that goal. You might track if they activated the button (keyboard or mouse shouldn’t be relevant) and keep the dialogue if they tried to close it otherwise. It shouldn’t matter how they comply

Comment: why did the dialogs from bootstrap get these configuration properties then?

Comment: You need to ask the Bootstrap maintainers that question. Including how that works with accessibility and aria

Comment: @stwissel and Patrick, the "keyboard: false" setting does not disable the keyboard - it only removes the option to press the escape key to close the dialog/modal